# Unable to rename/copy the root field name in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Here is my sample config LS 7.9.

```
input {
  jdbc { ... }
}

filter {
json {
     
    #It's JSON field from DB, including only two for reference.
    source => "tags_json"  

    #Need it as Sub-field like tags.companies, tags.geographies in ES
    add_field => {
      "[tags][companies]" => "%{companies}"
      "[tags][geographies]" => "%{geographies}"
    }

output {
  elasticsearch { ... }
}
```

JSON structure in DB field `tags_json`

```
{"companies": ["ABC","XYZ"], 
 "geographies": [{"Market": "Group Market", "Region": "Group Region", "Country": "my_country"}],
 "xyz":[]...
}
```

Logstash prints root `geographies` field correctly, this is what I need as sub-field under tags.

```
"geographies" => [
        [0] {
            "Market" => "Group Market",
            "Region" => "Group Region"
        },

## But as sub-field under the tags, only geographies is nil
"tags" => {
         "companies" => [
            [0] "ABC",
            [1] "XYZ"
        ],
        "geographies" => nil
    }
```

I tried below copy, ruby, but doesn't seem to fix it :
`mutate {  copy => { "%{geographies}" => "[tags][geographies]"} }`
Also tried Ruby
`ruby {  code => " event.set('[tags][geographies]', event.get('%{geographies}')) " }`

Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: For the ruby filter that should be event.get('geographies'), not a sprintf reference.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it with ruby event.

```
ruby {
    code => 'event.set("[tags][geographies]", event.get("geographies"))'
  }
```